# What's the simplest versioning software for extremely small (usually single-file) projects?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

many times I'll find myself having extremely small projects that consist of just a day or two of work. My example right now is a simple single-file HTML and javascript file to submit a form to an external website. It's not going to be something I'll whip up in 10 minutes, but it's also not going to take me more than a day or two of coding.

I would really like versioning for projects like these though because I tend to have quite a few of them, and almost always I end up kicking myself later for not having a revision to roll back to after I break something. '

I know of SVN, but it feels really clunky for storing just 1 small file with maybe 4 or 5 commits. I mean, I'd have to go through the hassle of making a repository, and all that. I really just want a kind of super simple versioning. I don't need any advanced features, just a `commit` and `rollback` type thing.

Does anyone know of any versioning software geared toward this kind of light weight versioning?

To refine my question a bit, I define "best" as being easy to use and for me to spend a minimal amount of time managing it. I don't expect a ton of features. I'll never need anything like branches, or having other people edit it. Just a less manual and simpler equivalent of

```
cp myfile myfile.backup1
```

Note, I'm on Linux, and really would like a super simple command line interface. But GUIs work too :)

Comment: @marc_s I tried to refine my question a bit. Best is most simple for me to use and that I spend the least amount of time having to manage

Comment: You could also consider all your single-day programming tasks as a single *Misc* project (containing one sub-directory for each such task), and manage that *Misc* project under a real version control system (like `git`)

Answer (score 3):

I would go with git.

With git you can create a new git repository in a new source dir with just:

```
git init
```

This creates a new repository in the current directory.  You can then check in files in the same directory with:

```
git add *
git commit -a
```

And that's about all there is to versioning your files.

Another option is the antiquated [RCS](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rcsintro).  It has no support for remote repositories and it's not terribly featureful, but if all you need is some basic version control then it could do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) on a directory on your drive. No need to install SVN Server. That way you got everything locally in form of a directory that you can always move if needed.  I'm assuming you work on Windows.

I use that myself with 2 other colleagues that work from this Shared Directory until we get a server to move it to real SVN or TFS. I've been using that solution myself for years (without colleagues that arrived recently).

Comment: I have a real SVN server setup already, and I know how to use `file:///` SVN repos. I don't want to have to go through all of the hassle of creating a new repo, remembering where it is, etc.

Comment: Well in Windows it's as simple as doing right click on Directory and doing Import and typing in project name and then you just checkout and do commits. There's nothing to remember..

Comment: Ah, I didn't know Tortoise SVN made things quite that simple! Regardless, I'm actually using Linux. While, I wish there was a Tortoise SVN port for it, the only good SVN tools is the `svn` command as far as I've seen for Linux

Comment: @Earlz: Reading your comments one thing bugs me: Why do you want to create a new repo for each flywight project? Why not using just one repo containing all your flywigth project using several subdirectories? This move reduces much of the overhead and introduces several advantages (like - "it's small, it _must_ be there" queries after a year or so)

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub](https://github.com/) with [Github for Windows](http://windows.github.com/)/[Mac](http://mac.github.com/) should be good for you. The UI is simple to use and doesn't require much skill to learn. Also, most IDE's have Git integration, so a GUI might not even be required.

Answer (score 0):

Try pv2 . http://code.google.com/p/pv2.

Comment: That project had might as well not exist. There is no source code, despite being listed as "GPL"

Answer (score 0):

I would use any of the distributed VCS like Mercurial, Git or Bazaar. They all have the repository in place with your working copy.